# Phonegap Build IOS App not showing Is ICON/Launch Image

Tags: ios, cordova

My IOS application is created with phonegap build which was not showing its Icon/Launch Image.
I have include icon image in res/icon/ios folder with size `57*57, 114*114, 40*40, 80*80, 120*120, 50*50, 100*100, 60*60, 120*120, 180*180, 72*72, 144*144, 76*76, 152*152, 29*29, 58*58, 87*87` .And Config file having path to icon image is

```
<icon src="icon.png"/>
<platform name="ios">
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon.png"  width="57" height="57"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png"  width="114" height="114"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40.png"  width="40" height="40"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png"  width="80" height="80"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50.png"  width="50" height="50"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png"  width="100" height="100"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png"  width="60" height="60"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png"  width="120" height="120"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png"  width="180" height="180"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"  width="72" height="72"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png"  width="144" height="144"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png"  width="76" height="76"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png"  width="152" height="152"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small.png"  width="29" height="29"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png"  width="58" height="58"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@3x.png"  width="87" height="87"/>
<icon height="87" src="res/icon/ios/icon-87.png" width="87" />
<icon height="58" src="res/icon/ios/icon-58.png" width="58" />
```

My www folder structure is

and res/icon/ios structure is

But Ios build version completely ignored this icon images.
I create ipa file  with build.phonegap.com , and to check icon image , I extract this ipa file , then get file structure like Payload/ShreeMedical.app contaning various size AppIcon and LaunchImages and but all are black image not my icon image.
Untitled.pngHow to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have that icons names will match icons names in info.plist file

Comment: there is  no file with name info.plist

Comment: I am creating app in phonegap build

Answer (score 0):

check your app icons here Assets.xcassets -> AppIcon.appiconset , there has Contents json and icon images you can give image names in json and images in that folder then it automatically set.

same for launch images also "Assets.xcassets -> LaunchImage.launchimage" give names in Contents json and give images in the same folder

once check below image for reference

[image]

Comment: I am creating phonegap application for IOS platform using phonegap desktop, phonegap developer app and visual studio on Windows machine not Mac. Here I am not getting Assets.xcassets folder